# How to combine create user and delete user with Apple authentication in firebase for swiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make authentication with apple account for swiftUi.

In firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?hl=en&authuser=0#enable-apple-as-a-sign-in-provider)

It says we should use this code for creating user.

```
extension MainViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
      let credential = OAuthProvider.appleCredential(withIDToken: idTokenString,
                                                        rawNonce: nonce,
                                                        fullName: appleIDCredential.fullName)
      Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if error {
          // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
          // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
          // your request to Apple.
          print(error.localizedDescription)
          return
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // Handle error.
    print("Sign in with Apple errored: \(error)")
  }

}
```

It also says we should use this for deleting user:

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController,
                             didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
  Task {
    do {
      try await Auth.auth().revokeToken(withAuthorizationCode: authCodeString)
      try await user?.delete()
      self.updateUI()
    } catch {
      self.displayError(error)
    }
  }
}
```

So how can i combine these or should i use them in separated viewmodels.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this?